# iOS api exposurePointOfInterest time

Tags: ios

How much time does the iOS API `exposurePointOfInterest` take for settling the exposure metering around the point? Is the time fixed? Do we have any fixed timings for iPhone devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's variable. If you monitor changes to `adjustingExposure`, you'll see that it sometimes makes quick changes, sometimes longer changes.

Comment: Thats true. I have observed varying times. But is there any upper limit on this time?

Comment: I don't know of an upper limit. Can you describe more about the problem you're trying to solve? I'm working on a camera app myself. The camera I'm using (iPad 3 rear) doesn't support `AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose`, so I've had to work around that (by monitoring `adjustingExposure`, etc.).